# Ordering query results by row repetitions without join

Tags: sql, database, oracle

So basically, I want to order my query by how many times a given column has a value. I have done this by doing a join with another query that counts the repetitions, but I would like to avoid the other extensive query. I'm thinking there might be some trick with order by that does what I want.

NOTE: The query I'm working with is huge and filled with company info, so I'm going to write an example query that exemplifies my problem.

Using

```
SELECT user1, rev1, user2, rev2, userCount
FROM someTable,
    (SELECT user2, count(*) userCount
     FROM someTable
     WHERE something1 = something2) counts
WHERE something1 = something2
AND counts.user2 = someTable.user2
ORDER BY userCount DESC
```

I get the correct result, so I tried

```
SELECT user1, rev1, user2, rev2 
FROM someTable
WHERE something1 = something2
ORDER BY COUNT(user2) DESC
```

but this doesn't yield the results I want.

Is there some SQL trick that solves this for me?

Thanks!

Comment: I don't fully understand the examples, so is this close? `SELECT user1, rev1, rev2, COUNT(user2) FROM someTable WHERE something1=something2 GROUP BY user1, rev1, rev2 ORDER BY COUNT(user2)`. If that isn't right please post sample `someTable` rows and expected output - I'm sure someone can help.

Comment: Do you also want the `COUNT` displayed?  If so, you'd need to put it into the `SELECT` portion.  Also, you don't have `DESC` in your second `ORDER BY` so you may be wanting your results sorted that way.

Comment: I cant write DESC on the second one since I get an error. I get `ORA-00937: not a single-group group function`. I'm going to try Gordon's suggestion in a minute.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
SELECT user1, rev1, user2, rev2, COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY user2) as c
FROM someTable
WHERE something1 = something2
ORDER BY c DESC
```

edit: beated by Gordon from 30secs!! .)

Comment: This looks a lot more elegant and is exactly what I needed.

Comment: Is there any way I can make it only give me the top 10 different?

Comment: That will not work for me because I might get more than 1 row which matches the C value (and that's how I want it). I want to get the top 10 user2, then return all the results which have the same user2 as that

Comment: you'll need a subquery then, is that ok?

Comment: Will it retain the speed of the `COUNT(user2) OVER (PARTITION BY user2) as c`?

Comment: Try it out, but don't be tricked by the comfort of the window/analytic function. It is NOT fast. A good join is going to give you the same result. I edited my answer.

Comment: The first one actually lowered my time in half. :)

Comment: tell me whats'up with the new query then :-)

Comment: It takes around the same as the other query. I have tried other ways of lowering the time complexity on it, but it seems like I'm stuck.

Answer (score 3):

Your query doesn't work because you are using a `count()` without a corresponding `group by`.  It just doesn't make sense, because you don't have an aggregation query.

A good way to do what you want to do is using analytic functions:

```
SELECT user1, rev1, user2, rev2 
FROM (select t.*,
             COUNT(*) over (partition by user2) as numuser2
      from someTable
      WHERE something1 = something2
     ) t
ORDER BY numuser2 desc, user2
```

The `count(*) over` syntax is going to count the rows for each `user2` value and append that to the row.

By the way, I also added `user2` to the `order by`.  This way, if some values have the same count, they will still be separated.

Answer (score 0):

Using an extensive query is not necessarily evil if you can get faster performance. Having said that, it's hard to tell what's your reason for not wanting to use the first query. Are you experiencing a performance problem? If then, it would be help what indexes your tables are using.

Anyway, the nested query in your first query seems to be missing the "GROUP BY" clause. The "something1 = something2" can mean different things in terms of performance or result. So, it would be helpful if you can put more concrete example.

Comment: I'm trying to shave my query down, and I'm thinking this might lower it about half the time.